# Is it possible to code iOS app to make music app go to next song?

Tags: ios

So I'm not sure if it's possible to make the native music player on iOS flip to next song from the request of another app.

How would I call from my app for the music app to flip to the next song?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot tell the music app or any other apps to skip a song.

Each app has its own instance of whatever music playing controller it may be using, and so there's no way you can interact directly with it.